# SQL Format as of Round off removing decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, decimal

I have a calculated field 'MySum' in inner query whose value after calculation is 58.

I need to get 20% of this value.

If I give:

```
MySum * 20 /100, I get 11
```

If I give:

```
((20 * CAST(MySum as decimal(6,2)))/100) , I get 11.60000
```

If I give

```
Round(((20 * CAST(MySum as decimal(6,2)))/100), 2), I still get 11.60000
```

I want that,

If result comes 11.6, it should display 12 and if result is 11.4, it should display 11.

I want to Rounded off values. Any function for that ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use ROUND () [(See examples )](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions/) function in sql server

```
select round(11.6,0)
```

result:

```
12.0
```

ex2:

```
select round(11.4,0)
```

result:

```
11.0
```

if you don't  want the decimal part, you could do

```
select cast(round(11.6,0) as int)
```

Comment: I do not want decimal places at all. Like if instead of Round, I use CEILING. The value format which I get in CEILING, same I need here, but by rounding off values.

Comment: @RMN: Please see the last select statement in my answer

Comment: It works with OLEDB as well. I used it in a DBF table (foxpro) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Try this and you'll get an error
select cast(round(0.60,0) as bigint)

Answer (score 1):

```
CAST(Round(MySum * 20.0 /100, 0) AS INT)
```

FYI

> > MySum * 20 /100, I get 11

This is because when all 3 operands are INTs, SQL Server will do perform integer maths, from left to right, truncating all intermediate results.

```
58 * 20 / 100 => 1160 / 100 => 11 (truncated from 11.6)
```

Also for the record **ROUND(m,n)** returns the result to n decimal places, **not** n significant figures.

Comment: My mistake, i did not mention. Even Round(((20 * CAST(MySum as decimal(6,2)))/100), 0), gives 12.00000 but I want only 12, eliminating digits after decimal.

Comment: Which the `CAST( as INT)` does.

Answer (score 1):

check the [round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175003%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function and how does the `length` argument works. It controls the behaviour of the precision of the result

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 11.4)
```

RESULT: 11

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, 11.6)
```

RESULT: 11